# Prometheus rule for not exist metrics

Tags: prometheus, metrics, rules

Good afternoon, can you please explain how to properly format a Prometheus rule for metrics with unique labels? I have an application that generates metrics for Prometheus based on events, with a unique UID in each metric. I need to create an alert that includes these labels for each event. Since there are no metrics like "changes," "increase," etc., I cannot use them because they won't trigger if the metric did not exist prior. Additionally, I need the alert to turn off after one hour.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
MYMETRIC unless MYMETRIC offset 10m
```